# Set default R exponential notation and decimal digits?

Tags: r

There are several questions on how to change these parameters, but I would like to change these options permanently, how can I do that so I don't have to reset these everytime I open a new session?

Comment: See the `?Startup` help page for the list of places you can put code that you want to run automatically every time you want to start R (such as code to set your digit preferences). That's pretty much how you would make a "permanent change" like this.

Comment: @MrFlick is correct, however I caution you to think seriously about any global variables you change. Fiddling with default settings can have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza what consequences exactly? It sounds so vague.

Comment: Any time you're changing any defaults, it changes the assumptions that other people's code makes. That means that some packages or code that you copy from the Internet can work unexpectedly.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza I get that, but here we are talking about display of numbers, it will not change the value itself.

Comment: I doubt it'll mess up anything important, but I just wanted to make the observation that changing R's defaults goes against best practices. If you ever make a package I recommend resetting everything to default.